# css animation delay with Angular ngIf directive

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-directive

I have a component with ngIf directive.

I would that when `*ngIf` is true render the element but with a **delay** of 200ms.

```
<app-kpi1
    [ngStyle]="{ transition: 'transform 400ms ease-out', 'transition-delay': '200ms' }"
    *ngIf="!isNavExpanded"
></app-kpi1>
```

I tried with `ngStyle` but animation is rendered directly without a delay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property that you want is called an animated delay as in the example below:

```
div {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
```

References:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-delay.asp